# Parse trigger error, afterFind expect results to be returned in the promise

Tags: javascript, triggers, cloud, parse-server

I'm having an error when I try to use a simple afterFind trigger.
I'm using Parse Server v4.2.0 via back4app

```
Parse.Cloud.afterFind('Device', async (req) => {
   console.log(req);
});
```

but the app crashes and start to prompt the error message

```
afterFind expect results to be returned in the promise
```

I noticed two things:

- The error is also in the Device class
- The error is only in some function

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using `async`, it is expecting the promise to resolve to a query result. You have two options:

1. since you are not using `await` in your trigger, you can just remove the `async` from your function:

```js
Parse.Cloud.afterFind('Device', (req) => {
   console.log(req);
});
```

2. You can return the objects at the end:

```js
Parse.Cloud.afterFind('Device', async (req) => {
   console.log(req);
   return req.objects;
});
```

Comment: Thank you Davi!! Both answers worked. 
I have one question tho, why the return in the async type is a req.objects? I couldn't find documentation for that and I my tries were 
```return req```
```return req.results```
among others.

Comment: Nevermind, I was looking in the afterFind object and there is the ```req.objects```. I didn't see that before 'cause I wasn't able to debug the object before. (I'm not deleting the previous comment in order to keep that answer for the rest)